# Vuex throwing "do not mutate..." on dispatching updated deep object from data()

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to build a filter component with multiple fields

```
data: () => ({
  loanFilter: {
    title: null,
    user: null,
    amount: null,
    apr: null,
    rate: null,
    rating: null,
  },
}),

<v-text-field label="Title" v-model="loanFilter.title"></v-text-field>
// (...)
```

the idea is: all those inputs write to the data object, then i have a watcher that dispatches changes to the store:

```
watch: {
  loanFilter: {
    handler: function (val) {
      this.$store.dispatch('loan/updateLoanFilter', val)
    },
    deep: true,
  },
},
```

now if i enter something like "aaaaa" in the inputs,
the **first** character works,
the **second** one throws

```
[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "function () { return this._data.$$state }": "Error: [vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."

(found in <Root>)
warn @ vue.esm.js?efeb:591
logError @ vue.esm.js?efeb:1737
globalHandleError @ vue.esm.js?efeb:1732
handleError @ vue.esm.js?efeb:1721
run @ vue.esm.js?efeb:3235
update @ vue.esm.js?efeb:3207
notify @ vue.esm.js?efeb:697
reactiveSetter @ vue.esm.js?efeb:1014
set @ vue.esm.js?efeb:1036
callback @ FilterLoans.vue?6c61:18
invoker @ vue.esm.js?efeb:2027
Vue.$emit @ vue.esm.js?efeb:2538
e.(anonymous function) @ backend.js:1
set @ vuetify.js?dc48:13367
onInput @ vuetify.js?dc48:13581
invoker @ vue.esm.js?efeb:2027
fn._withTask.fn._withTask @ vue.esm.js?efeb:1826
14:19:29.294 vue.esm.js?efeb:1741 Error: [vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
    at assert (vuex.esm.js?358c:97)
    at Vue.store._vm.$watch.deep (vuex.esm.js?358c:746)
    at Watcher.run (vue.esm.js?efeb:3233)
    at Watcher.update (vue.esm.js?efeb:3207)
    at Dep.notify (vue.esm.js?efeb:697)
    at Object.reactiveSetter [as title] (vue.esm.js?efeb:1014)
    at Proxy.set (vue.esm.js?efeb:1036)
    at callback (FilterLoans.vue?6c61:18)
    at VueComponent.invoker (vue.esm.js?efeb:2027)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$emit (vue.esm.js?efeb:2538)
```

even though i'm not mutating it in any way.

if i change the watcher to `this.$store.dispatch('loan/updateLoanFilter', 'any hardcoded string')`, it works (but then the filter is that string of course...)

if i change the watcher to `this.$store.dispatch('loan/updateLoanFilter', this.loanFilter)`, i get the same error

it seems just reading it is considered mutating here? and i'm not even reading the store, but just that component's data object! why is that? how can i fix it? thanks!

Comment: Can you show code of `updateLoanFilter` action function?

Comment: sure:
  updateLoanFilter({ commit }, params) {
    console.log('updating loan filter:', params)
    commit('SET_LOAN_FILTER', params)
  },

Comment: and the mutation:   SET_LOAN_FILTER(state, payload) {
    this.state.loan.loanFilter = payload
  },

Comment: i just thought you had enlightened me :D i removed `this.` from the mutation. but still the same error :(